# How to make smooth scroll to the view focused using requestChildFocus?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a childView inside ScrollView which expands onClick. I used the below code to bring the expanded view fully in the screen.

`scrollView.requestChildFocus(childView, focussedView);`

But the scroll is not smooth. What can I do to make the scroll smooth?

Comment: Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and I'll try to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `smooth scroll` methods provided by `ScrollView`. Here is the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#setSmoothScrollingEnabled(boolean)).

Try these methods:

```
public void setSmoothScrollingEnabled(boolean smoothScrollingEnabled)
// Set whether arrow scrolling will animate its transition.

public final void smoothScrollTo(int x, int y)
// Like scrollTo(int, int), but scroll smoothly instead of immediately.

public final void smoothScrollBy(int dx, int dy)
// Like View.scrollBy(int, int), but scroll smoothly instead of immediately.
```

Comment: Is a way to do the same thing using requestChildFocus

Comment: Try using `setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);` and then use `requestChildFocus`.